# Server forbids access to any URL ending in .php (even nonexistent ones) with "client denied by server configuration", but identical html files are OK

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I'm trying to enable some php files on an Apache 2.4 machine that has no other php content.  I'm finding that any php URL (even made-up URLs for nonexistent things) results in the error "client denied by server configuration".  Renaming the same file to something ending in .html makes the error go away, and the content of the file is then visible in the browser.

The fact that renaming the file removes the error, and the fact that the error happens even for nonexistent files, makes me think this isn't a permissions issue. (I've also tried toggling selinux off, and that doesn't change anything.) I've searched through the apache configuration files looking for anything that would explicitly deny access to .php files, but have found nothing.

As far as I can tell, the necessary php packages are installed.  For completeness, this machine is running Almalinux 8, and is otherwise serving web pages successfully.

Any tips for diagnosing this problem would be appreciated. It would be especially helpful if I could cause the server to tell me why access is denied.

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved.  By doing an `httpd -DDUMP_CONFIG -k start` to dump apache's complete configuration, I found a configuration directive I'd missed (inherited from another machine) that simply denied access to any .php file.  Everything works now.